# stopPropagation() does not work for delegate event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

i am trying to toggle `.abb-bar`, using `$.toggle()` whenever its parent( `.abb` ) gets a click. but whenever `.abb-bar` gets a click, its toggles itself because of `event-bubbling`. `e.stopPropagation()` should solve the problem but it does not work. what can be done?

HTML

```
<span class="col-auto entry-ops abb">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <div class="list-group abb-bar">
        <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-center" data-user="nick">follow</button>
        <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-center complain">complain</button>
        <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-center show-entry-number" data-toggle="tooltip">'.$row['entry_id'].'</button>
    </div>
</span>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.abb', function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.abb-bar').toggle();
});
```

Comment: stopPropagation would stop events from firing that are parents of it... not the children... but you are sitting at document, so the click has already gotten there.

Comment: i didnt get it why people downvote others answers and don't give reason for that

Comment: @krishnar Your answer is probably downvoted because the answer did only include code and no explaining text. Try adding some explanation of what is changed by your code to create a better received answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using event delegation here.

By the time the event reaches `document`, there's only one more element for it to propagate to (`window`). It has already propagated up to `document` so you can't retroactively cancel it for elements it's already fired on. This is the very nature of event delegation... Let the event bubble all the way up and then see which element originated the event.

You only need to set a click event on the toggle element and cancel the click event on the child container.

```js
// Set the click event handler on the toggle area
$('.abb').on('click', function( e ) {
    $('.abb-bar', this).toggle();
});

// Don't enable the click event on the child
$('.abb-bar').on('click', function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="col-auto entry-ops abb">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">Click to toggle</i>
    <div class="list-group abb-bar">
        <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-center" data-user="nick">follow</button>
        <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-center complain">complain</button>
        <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-center show-entry-number" data-toggle="tooltip">'.$row['entry_id'].'</button>
    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: I didnt get it why its necessary to send this to toggle

Comment: @krishnar `abb-bar` is  what needs to be toggled. `this` (as a second parameter to the selector) simply supplies context for where it can be found. It's a way to improve performance and is highly recommended in complex DOM structures. It's not required. It would be reqired if there were more than one `.abb-bar` element as this would keep the others from toggling as well.